# Multiplying of a function for a rectangularPulse - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm wondering if it's possible to multiplying a function for a rectangularPulse.

I tried to wrote this code, but it's wrong:

```
Tc = 0.01;                         
t = [0:Tc:3];
y = t.^2 * rectangularPulse(1,2,t);
```

Can you tell me if there is a solution (I want to use rectangularPulse, not other function)?

The error is the following:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in aaa (line 12)
y = t.^2 * rectangularPulse(1,2,t);
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "but it's wrong", why?

Comment: Hello @AnderBiguri, I edited my question.

Comment: Have you searched for the error you have? It is one of the most common errors in MATLAB. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri, I know it (when I use vectors), but I don't know how fix the code because I have functions.

Comment: The output of  `rectangularPulse` is a vector, not a fucntion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplication should be a element-wise multiplication:

```
y = t.^2 .* rectangularPulse(1,2,t);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @PedroRodriguez.